# Pandastream heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pandastream

I have followed the pandastream setup docs on Heroku, available here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pandastream

However when using `heroku run console` and executing `Panda::Profile.all` I get

```
irb(main):001:0> Panda::Profile.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `connection' for nil:NilClass
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda/modules/cloud_connection.rb:4:in `connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda/modules/finders.rb:19:in `find_object_by_path'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda/modules/finders.rb:23:in `find_by_path'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda/modules/finders.rb:44:in `all'
    from (irb):1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Testing it locally works fine with the intended results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sanity checks

1. Did you create the file `config/initializers/panda.rb` as given in guide for initializer?
2. Run `heroku addons:open pandastream` & verify your S3 bucket and credentials. a wrong credential will most likely lead to `connection error` like you are seeing in your stack trace
3. try update to the latest version of `typhoeus` & `panda` to see if that helps

Hope it helps. And don't forget to Post back, if none of this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, I've asked the question at a point of crazyness. I got it working eventually with the sanity check approach :).